# MySql DB connections are not stable and growing high in number in our application

Tags: database, connection

We use sequelize as our ORM with MySQL in node. Js application. The pool max is 5 and min is 2. Still it creates db connection growing more. In 15 mins it establish connection upto 50 I can't find out why it persist. It creating the connection increasing in number